# ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4.3.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file):

Tags: python, linux, compiler-errors, google-colaboratory

Code:

```
import os
os.environ["LD_PRELOAD"] = ""
!apt update
!apt remove libtcmalloc-minimal4
!apt install libtcmalloc-minimal4
os.environ["LD_PRELOAD"] = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4.3.0"
!echo $LD_PRELOAD
!apt update
```

Trying this code on google collab but getting the error ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4.3.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): please help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the version of libtcmalloc_minimal you are using. In your error log, you would have a list of all the libraries available. For me, the version was 4.5.9.

Try changing the `os.environ["LD_PRELOAD"]` to `"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4.5.9"`

You might also have to instal the libglu1 library using `!apt-get install libglu1`